# Stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql

> Procedure or function 'insert_territory' expects parameter '@name', which was not supplied.

```
public void add_record_territory(territory t)
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert_territory",con);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",t.Name);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regdate", DateTime.Now);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regtime", DateTime.Now);
  con.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
}
```

Comment: value in the name parameter might be null or empty string.

Comment: You're using `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` with MySQL?

Comment: As per the comment that @David made, I would switch to using `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand` at the very least. You should always try to use the proper types for things like this. Internally they operate slightly differently depending on what the underlying connection goes to.

Comment: I am using sqlmanagemnt studio 2012

Comment: @NaflanMohdeen: *"I am using sqlmanagemnt studio 2012"* - You're using tools for connecting to and interacting with SQL Server, but the tags on your question indicate that you're connecting to MySQL.  If misleading information is given in your question that only makes it more difficult for the community to help.

Comment: when i was load the data from database to grid it's work but insert the data i was get error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if name null then use

```
DBNull.Value
```

for "@name" value

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@application_ex_id",
       ((object)logSearch.LogID) ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: Its Work null value was save. i think "<input class="form-control"  name='name' placeholder="territory" ng-model="territory.Name" required>" text box not pass the values variable call "  public string Name { get; set; } (terriyoru class)"

Answer (score 0):

First make sure "t.Name" is not null

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert_territory", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;        
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",t.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regdate", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regtime", DateTime.Now);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }            
}
```

Comment: I was put break point run t.Name is get null values

Comment: Mvc with angularjs if i  save the data separately form its work